# strtotime not giving result

Tags: php, strtotime

Why is the following code

```
$first_day = strtotime('first day of this month', '2012-06-01');
echo $first_day;
```

Not returning any result? The string is empty.

Comment: What is the version of your php, first day of will work only with php 5.3+, if your version is less than that please check my answer i edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

If php version less than 5.3

```
<?php 
$d = date_create();
print date_create($d->format('Y-m-1'))->format('Y-m-d') 
?>
```

If php version 5.3+

```
<?php
    $d = new DateTime('2012-06-20');
    $d->modify('first day of this month');
    echo $d->format('jS, F Y');
?>
```

Here is another solution :

```
<?php 

echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime( 'first day of '.date('2012-06-01'))); ///time stamp

echo strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime( 'first day of '.date('2012-06-01')))); // formated date

?>
```

Comment: returns the following: Warning: DateTime::modify() [datetime.modify]: Failed to parse time string (first day of this month) at position 10 (o): The timezone could not be found in the database

Comment: Strange ! it works fine for me, ref : http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Comment: Edited the answer please check it now

Comment: @PrasanthBendra may be date_parse_from_format() instead of strtotime() will work..

Comment: @PrasanthBendra even my code works for me too so may be date parsing is not working so moving OP to date_parse_from_format let see if that work for him

Comment: My php version was indeed less than 5.3 and above code is working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you say didn't get any response because your given second parameter in `strtotime` function is not timestamp.

So first convert into timestamp..

see below code  :

```
$first_day = strtotime('first day of this month', strtotime('2012-06-01'));
```

Comment: @DipeshParmar sry strtotime

Answer (score 0):

Just use it as below,

```
$first_day = strtotime('2012-06-01');
echo $first_day;
```

First date of month

```
<?php
    echo strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime( 'first day of '.date('2012-06-01')));
?>
```

if its not work try `date_parse_from_format()` instead of `strtotime()`

Comment: And what to do if the date is 2012-06-02 and I want the timestamp of the first day of that month?

Comment: I did, I always get 1970-01-01 as a result

Comment: is year month and date separated with - sign.?